# Tomcat: Have I messed up my jndi connection set up or what?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, tomcat, jdbc

I am using Tomcat's 7 connection pool. My configuration is the following:
In `server.xml`:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="jdbc_DS" auth="Container"   
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"  
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"  
              driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"  
              url="jdbc:h2:file:absolutePathtodatabase"  
              username="root" password=""  
              maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"  
              />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

And in context.xml:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/myDS"  
        global="jdbc_DS"  
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

It seems to work but I noticed the following:
In the attributes of resource [here:global resources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html) it doesn't mention `factory` as attribute of a `Resource`.Nevertheless I have defined it in `server.xml`and got no error.
What does this mean?Am I not using a `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory` factory here?

Answer (score 1):

But you aren't using a `<Resource>` in `context.xml`, you are using a `<ResourceLink>`, so whatever attributes a `<Resource>` may have in `context.xml` is irrelevant. The `<ResourceLink>` just has enough attributes to refer to the `<Resource>`, which is fully defined elsewhere, including its `factory` attribute.

Comment: I am referring to `<Resource>` attributes in `server.xml`.This doesn't seem to have a `factory` attribute

Comment: @Jim The same thing in `context.xml` does have a factory attribute. I would try it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Tomcat 7 documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) tells us, that you're configuration is correct for using a data source factory:

> The Tomcat Connection pool is configured as a resource described in [The Tomcat JDBC documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) With the only difference being that you have to specify the factory attribute and set the value to `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory`

The [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html) further mentions:

> You **MUST** also define any other needed parameters using attributes on the Resource element, to configure the object factory to be used (if not known to Tomcat already), and the properties used to configure that object factory.

which is another hint, that the list of valid elements is not complete.

Comment: In the link you given, the reference is to a `Resource` defined in the `context.xml`.But I am using the `GlobalNamingResources` in `server.xml`.Am I wrong to use `server.xml`?Plenty of examples I have seen googling use `server.xml`

Comment: I see no difference between global and local "`<Resource>` declarations". You use the global ones with `<ResourceLink>` and would expect the very same attributes. Otherwise you couldn't declare "complete" Resources globally.

Comment: My concern is the following:The `resource` as nested component in the `context.xml` is defined to have a `factory` attribute in the link of doc.But the `resource` as nested component in `server.xml` (nested in `globalresources`) does not seem to have one.Are you saying that this element is the same in both xml files (`server.xml` and `context.xml`)?